# Mahalaya tarpane by adapted son

Tags: pitru

An adoption is done after correct homa and rituals. Now the adapted son while giving tarpana has to give to his adapted father as pitr. What about pitamah and prapitamah. Shud it be his original grandfather and great grandfather?

Comment: Adoption is almost similar to similar to kanyadana. Once the rites of adoption has been completed, the adopted person ceases to have any obligation towards his/her biological parents. So the man in question must offer pinda-tarpana to his adoptive father, grandfather & great-grandfather. However, the person isn't prohibited from offering pinda-tarpana to them, because in our scriptures sanctions offering these even to people not related by blood like friends & servants.

Comment: I imagine after adoption , his gotra might be changed. Also the adoptees if willingly giving in adoption, in the days। when adoption was by religious rite, would have seen to it that they had scions to offer shradha.